# How rows are removed from original table if we use cte for removing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

If we use CTE for removing duplicates, delete from cte works -that is deletes rows from original table. How it happens?

If we update CTE for some value, that is not reflected in original table, why it is so?

For eg:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_DUPLICATEREMOVALTEST
 (
   ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(20)
  )

 INSERT INTO TABLE_DUPLICATEREMOVALTEST
 SELECT 1,'hina'
 union all
 SELECT 1,'hina'
 union all
 SELECT 1,'hina'
 union all
 SELECT 2,'Tina'
 union all
 SELECT 3,'Mina'
 union all
 SELECT 4,'Lina'
 union all
 SELECT 5,'Sina'

 -- To test update
 alter table TABLE_DUPLICATEREMOVALTEST
 add Row_no INT


 ;WITH CTE (rNO,Row_no)
  AS
  (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,NAME ORDER BY ID, NAME) AS rNO, id
         FROM TABLE_DUPLICATEREMOVALTEST
  )
  UPDATE CTE SET Row_no = 100 WHERE Rno = 1  ---Not updating column in the main table
--DELETE FROM CTE WHERE Rno ! = 1 ---but this removes rows from main table

  SELECT * FROM TABLE_DUPLICATEREMOVALTEST
```

Can anyone help? I googled it but never found anything satisfactory..

Comment: The update should be working.  Are you certain that you have the correct data in front of you?

Comment: It is not updating Row_no  column, instead it is updating ID column

Comment: because you are giving Row_no alias to id.  Add original Row_no column to select part and change with part to WITH CTE (rNO,id,Row_no)